# Why $Assumptions is not working?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Consider the following code. Why Mathematica does not simplify the expression?

```
$Assumptions = {CC1 \[Element] Reals, CC2 \[Element] Reals, 
      CC3 \[Element] Reals, CC4 \[Element] Reals, CC5 \[Element] Reals, 
      CC6 \[Element] Reals, CC7 \[Element] Reals, CC8 \[Element] Reals, 
      CC9 \[Element] Reals, CC10 \[Element] Reals, CC11 \[Element] Reals, 
      CC12 \[Element] Reals}

f = (0.4673 + 0.4673 I) CC1 - (0.6283 + 0.8398 I) CC2 + (0.1138 + 
     0.1138 I) CC3 + (4.2071 - 4.564902775605618` I) CC4 + 
  1.3093 CC5 + 0.2524 CC6 + 4.8242*^154 CC7 + 2.8786*^-158 CC8

Re[f // Expand] // Simplify

Re[CC11] // Simplify
```

Comment: Have you tried `FullSimplify`

Comment: @mmeent: Hi. :) It seems that it does not work too!

Comment: (In case you are unaware, this exactly the sort of situation where `ComplexExpand` does exactly what you need.)

Comment: @mmeent: Of course, I was not aware! :D

Comment: @mmeent: I would be happy if you write an answer in this regard so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @mmeent, ComplexExpand does the simplification you are looking for.

```
f = (0.4673 + 0.4673 I) CC1 - (0.6283 + 0.8398 I) CC2 + (0.1138 + 
  0.1138 I) CC3 + (4.2071 - 4.564902775605618` I) CC4 + 
1.3093 CC5 + 0.2524 CC6 + 4.8242*^154 CC7 + 2.8786*^-158 CC8;
ComplexExpand[f // Re]

 0. + 0.4673 CC1 - 0.6283 CC2 + 0.1138 CC3 + 4.2071 CC4 + 1.3093 CC5 + 
 0.2524 CC6 + 4.8242*10^154 CC7 + 2.8786*10^-158 CC8
```

Comment: No need for the assumptions either. `ComplexExpand` assumes all Symbols are real.